# Extract the first number from a string number range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with price column as type of string, and some of the values in the form of range (15000-20000).
I want to extract the first number and convert the entire column to integers.

I tried this :

```
df['ptice'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-')[0])
```

The code just return the original column.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following options:

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'price': ['0','100-200','200-300']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

     price
0        0 # adding a str without `-`, to show that this one will be included too
1  100-200
2  200-300
```

**Option 1**

- Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` and select the first column from the result.
- Next, chain [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), and assign the result to `df['price']` to overwrite the original values.

```
df['price'] = df.price.str.split('-', expand=True)[0].astype(int)

print(df)

   price
0      0
1    100
2    200
```

**Option 2**

- Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex pattern, `r'(\d+)-?'`:
- `\d` matches a digit.
- `+` matches the digit 1 or more times.
- match stops when we hit `-` (`?` specifies "if present at all").

```
data = {'price': ['0','100-200','200-300']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['price'] = df.price.str.extract(r'(\d+)-?').astype(int)

# same result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].str.split('-', expand=True)[0].astype('int')
```

This will only store first number from the range. Example: From 15000-20000 only 15000 will be stored in the `price` column.